# Google Script to Split Right String Values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to perform Split function for a specific range.
Example, If i have a  string like "HYT008", I need to have only 008 as result, means I would like to split last 3 letters from a string.

Here is the scenario - [image]

In Google Sheet I will perform this condition as `=RIGHT(A2:A,3)`

In Google Apps Script, I need to perform the action.

Comment: what is the perceived benefit of having a script do this over having a formula do it?

Comment: Here's the JavaScript string methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: My Sheet is getting stuck while i perform the Right formula,

Comment: I have 30k+ data need to split like this

Comment: Have you tried `=arrayformula(right(a2:a30000,3))`

Comment: Array formula would work I guess but formulas are heavier than hardcopy values. If he does not need to have the values updated all the times then I also believe a script makes more sense. BTW I added the arrayformula solution for the shake of completion @TheMaster

Comment: @Marios Hardcoded values can be easily obtained by copy>paste values only. In fact script is only useful, if op needs to do this  repeatedly under  triggers or some kind of automation. One-offs are easily achieved with just formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

There are multiple ways you can do that in JavaScript.

- One way is to use the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method and get the last 3 elements of your string: `string.slice(-3)`.
- then you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to apply this operation to the full column of your choice:

  `sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().map(v=>[v.slice(-3)]);`

### Google Apps Script Solution:

The following script will get the values in column A, get the last 3 elements and paste them in column B:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // adjust this to the name of your sheet
  const values = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().map(v=>[v.slice(-3)]);
  sh.getRange(2,2,values.length,1).setValues(values); // paste them in column B
}
```

**Sheet used for the code snippet:**

[image]

---

### Google Sheets Formula Solution:

Here you don't need to define the last element of your column.

`=arrayformula(if(len(A2:A),right(A2:A,3),""))`

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @Moses I added also an arrayformula in case you can use it, could be quite useful.

Comment: Complete answer with good explanation. +1